Rice wine process
With regards to making Chinese or Japanese non distilled rice wine - can you just cook the rice in a rice cooker and then transfer the rice into sterised containers in two batches?
Then add the yeast water mixture.
How long does it take to achieve max alcohol content?
Thanks
